# XAMPP "module 'mysqli' already loaded" error?

Tags: xampp

Had XAMPP configured and running properly, was able to access phpmyadmin and execute php code on the local server.  This morning after starting XAMPP and starting Apache, I get a message saying: "module 'mysqli' already loaded."

I can't log into phpmyadmin- I see the login page, but when I click "go" I simply get a blank page.  I was practicing submitting forms into a DB, everything was working fine, now after submitting the form a message comes back: "connect failed with: (2002) A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. "

The XAMPP status page shows everything as being activated.  I don't remember making any config changes or doing anything else that could have caused this.

Appreciate any input.

Comment: some additional info- I'm not running anything that would be taking up port 80, so that's not an issue."  when I look into php.ini I see extension=php_mysqli_mysqlnd.dll
extension=php_mysqli_libmysql.dll
are uncommented, I'm pretty sure that's the way it's supposed to be, right?

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this by editing my php.ini and commenting these lines back out:

```
;extension=php_mysqli_mysqlnd.dll
;extension=php_mysqli_libmysql.dll
```

and typing in this line in their place:

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

disable or comment duplicate `extension=mysqli` in your `php.ini`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open your `php.ini` file and comment out the duplicate line below

> `extension=mysqli`                                                                          
> `;extension=mysqli`